# Android Game Dev: Input handling

Tags: java, android

I'm programming my first Android Game ever and I'm trying to figure out the best way to handle inputs.

Should I handle inputs outright or put them in a queue of some sort and handle them with an updateInputs() method?

Also, where should I put the code for handling inputs? Should it be inside my SurfaceView object or inside of the thread that handles drawing and physics?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put them in a queue but execute them right away, incase the processing takes longer then expected you can keep track of what the user has done. As for handling the imputs, i would put it in the surface view, but thats just my general opinion. Im sure there are better ways.

Good luck, I would like to play your game when you finish

Comment: So if I do use a queue what exactly do you mean when you say execute them right away?

Comment: Also, looking at the JetBoy sample from Google the doKeyDown event is inside of the thread rather than the view. Is this a better idea then putting it in the view?

Comment: As soon as there is some action inside a queue, it should executed. Inside the view you handle the event, but your right spawning a thread to handle it would make it more robust. Just make sure that the threads dont conflict with each other.